# Is it possible to calculate the height of an element that is constrained to a guideline?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, height

I have a ConstraintLayout with one element that is constrained only to a horizontal guideline:

```
    android:id="@+id/element"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

These are the horizontal guideline attributes:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4" />
```

Then, I can conclude that the height of the element would be the height of the usable screen * 0.6 as the element will occupy 60% of the screen.

My question is, could I calculate the exact height of that element with something like:

```
        double elementsheight = usablescreenheight * 0.6 ;
```

I have tried what I have said before but the calculated height was one pixel lower that the original height, but I think that there should be a way to calculate the exact height of the element before the drawing phase.

Comment: As per my understanding from your question you can do count it by :-  resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels * 0.6

Comment: @KhushParmar it should be something like that, I have used configuration to get the height as configuration gives usable screen. The problem I have is that when the height of the screen in px has decimals the calculated height is 1 pixel different thatn the orginial height...